# how could I make the PCmanFM don't display the windows system partition?

Tags: pcmanfm

I use the ubuntu and the windows system on my pc, when i open the file manage PCManFM 
in Lubuntu, the left side show me my windows partition,ie my C: D: partition in windows, but i don't won't it display here,
what should i do ?

I have unchecked the Edit->Preferences->Volume Management all three Auto-mount items,
but it doesn't work.

PS.I use the PCManFm 0.9.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an udev rule to hide the partitions.

### For Lubuntu 12.04

In this example I have two partition (NTFS).
**WIN-NTFS1** and **WIN-NTFS2**

[image]

**1)** Search information about your partitions.
Open a Terminal and type:

- `sudo blkid`

In my case the result is:

> /dev/sda1: UUID="c3338905-348b-47c8-bc55-f363bc487410" TYPE="ext4"
>
> /dev/sda3: LABEL="WIN-NTFS1" UUID="1F297ED5220E41AA" TYPE="ntfs"
>
> /dev/sda4: LABEL="WIN-NTFS2" UUID="4CFEB84C16B24904" TYPE="ntfs"
>
> /dev/sda5: UUID="4b1b8aac-4ee7-42ed-8ed6-3ab7443ee607" TYPE="swap"

Write down the device information eg:*(sda3)*, in my case:

> /dev/**sda3**: LABEL="WIN-NTFS1" UUID="1F297ED5220E41AA" TYPE="ntfs"
>
> /dev/**sda4**: LABEL="WIN-NTFS2" UUID="4CFEB84C16B24904" TYPE="ntfs"

**2)** Create the udev rule.
In the terminal window type:

- `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide-ntfs-partitions.rules`

Match the **"KERNEL"** key with you device and assign the **"UDISKS"** variable.

The content of the *99-hide-ntfs-partitions.rules* file would be:

> KERNEL=="sda3", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
>
> KERNEL=="sda4", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"

To save the changes in nano...

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

**3)** Finally refresh the udev rules with:

- `sudo udevadm trigger`

The result is :
[image]

### For Lubuntu 12.10 & 13.04.

The only difference is the name of the *UDISKS* variable.
It should be **ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}** instead **ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}**

The content of the *99-hide-ntfs-partitions.rules* file would be:

> KERNEL=="sda3", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
>
> KERNEL=="sda4", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"

Hope it helps.

Comment: why 12.10 different from 12.04? because the version of linux kernel?

Comment: I think because ubuntu 12.04 has udisk and 12.10 & 13.04 have udisk2. So the variable changes from ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE} in udisk. to ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE} in udisk2.

Comment: The second solution works in Lubuntu 14.04.1 :). You have to restart the system to have it working though.

Comment: Should also work in 16.04, right?

Comment: Works in 16.04. But I have a question. Why are some of my other partitions not displayed at all from the start? I have a Mac recovery partition and a Linux partition that don't come up in pcmanfm. Pcmanfm only showed the Win7 and main Mac partition.